# Pro-V topology on a free group

Tags: open-problems, profinite-groups

Let $W=G_p*G_q$, where $G_p$ and $G_q$ are pseudovarieties of
all finite $p$-groups and all finite $q$-groups respectively, with $p$ and $q$ fixed prime numbers. The pro-$W$ topology on a group $G$ is the unique group topology such that the set of normal subgroups $N$  with $G/N$ in $W$ is a fundamental system of neighborhoods of the identity.

Let $FG(A)$ be a finitely generated free group. Steinberg and Auinger proved that the pro-$W$ closure of a finitely generated subgroup $H$ of $FG(A)$ is also finitely generated.

Question. Let $H$ be a finitely generated subgroup of a finitely generated free group $FG(A)$. Is there an algorithm to compute a basis  for the pro-$W$ closure $H$ given as input a generating set for $H$?

We know that every minimal normal subgroup of a finite p-group $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$, hence $G$ has a finite normal series
$$1=N_1\leq N_2\leq \ldots N_m=G$$
such that $N_{i+1}/N_{i}\simeq  \mathbb{Z}_p$. Hence, we can write $G_q=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} V^i$ where $V$ is the locally finite pseudovariety generated by $\mathbb{Z}_q$ and $V^i={V*V*\ldots*V}$. By  Proposition 4.6 in "HALL VARIETIES OF FINITE SUPERSOLVABLE GROUPS", the $G_p*V$-closure of a finitely generated subgroup $H$ of $FG(A)$ is computable. By induction on $i$, we can prove that the $G_p*V^i$- closure of $H$ is computable. So, we have a chain
$$Cl_{Gp*V}(H)\geq Cl_{Gp*V^2}(H)\geq\ldots\geq Cl_{Gp*V^n}(H)\geq \ldots $$ of subgroups of $FG(A)$ containing $Cl_{G_p*G_q}(H)$. By Theorem 7.5 and Theorem 5.14 in "the geometry of profinite graphs with applications to free groups and finite monoids", every pseudovariety $G_p*V^i$ is Hall pseudovariety that means the automaton of $Cl_{G_p*V^i}(H)$ is a quotient of the automaton of $H$. Since $H$ is a finitely generated subgroup, the automaton of $H$ is finite and  so, the chain must stop somewhere and therefore there is $i$ such that
$Cl_{G_p*G_q}(H)=Cl_{Gp*V^i}(H)$. But the question is "Is there any bounded on $i$?

Comment: I believe this is still an open question and a good one.